# can we use case match to pattern again Option and normal value?

Tags: scala

I want to print the value if the it's not an option, and print the value inside the option if it's option. How to get that? The following doesn't work

```
val a="test"
def b= a match {
case i:Some[_] => i.getOrElse("1")
case _@x=>x
}
```

Comment: Please do not just say "doesn't work" and make the many readers each have to work out why. In what way doesn't it work?

Comment: As the answers point out, you end up requiring Any. This is a bit of a code-smell. Can you explain your use-case where you need this kind of code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val a:Any="test"
def b= a match {
  case Some(i) => i
  case None => "1"
  case x=>x
}
```

Comment: now it does, but you indeed need a common super type of String and Option which leads you to Any

Answer (score 4):

Something like this I think:

```
val a: Any = "test"
def b[T] = a match {
  case i: Option[T] => i.getOrElse("1")
  case _@x=>x
}
```

First `a` must be some supertype you can match on, if you had `a: String` matching on options would not be possible because you would already know that it's a string, note also that you have to pass a type parameter for option.